# Can you run the game Kindergarten on Linux

Tags: wine, steam

I have Wine installed, but I can't play any of my windows games. All that come up after I've bought the games is "Game Purchased" in place of where it would ask you to install or play the game. I've played around a little with wine but I can't add any applications when I configure the features.

Comment: Do you mean this game: http://store.steampowered.com/app/589590/Kindergarten/? And are you buying from Steam? Do you have steam installed? If you can't see the install button and you're using Steam, it's probably because you have the Linux version of Steam. You need to get the windows version of Steam and install via wine.

Comment: This is the windows version of steam: https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe (link is from http://store.steampowered.com/about/ and clicking on the windows link). To install via wine, you should just be able to double click and go, if not you can try using the terminal and typing in `wine /path/to/SteamSetup.exe` alternatively, and I highly recommend this way, is to use PlayOnLinux - makes it super easy to use wine for games - even gives you the option of installing Steam in the interface: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you've installed Steam through Linux, not Wine.

Steam is (currently) not smart enough to manage Wine installations and run Windows-only games through the native engine. If you want to play Windows games from Steam on Linux, you will need to install Steam itself on Wine.

Note that this will (usually) mean you have to deal with two Steam installs -- one native, and one installed through Wine. This is just the unfortunate state of Linux gaming at this time.

I would highly recommend you use [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) or some similar utility (such as CrossOver) to manage installation and Wine configuration, as they tend to remove most of the complicated Wine configurations that need to be done. However, if you'd rather use vanilla Wine, you can do that as well.